# Changing the character name in the output of `table()` in R?

Tags: r, string, function, character

I was wondering how I could change the name `foo` appearing in the top-left corner of the output of `b` in my R code below to `boo`?

```
foo <- sample(rep(1:3, 20))
b <- table(foo)
b
```

I tried the following with no success:

```
names(b) <- "boo"
```

Comment: It is `names(dimnames(b)) <- "boo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the character name using the parameter dnn.

```
foo <- sample(rep(1:3, 20))
b <- table(foo, dnn = "boo")
print(b)
#boo
# 1  2  3 
#20 20 20
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/table